# How to get data from react context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have a React class called `GlobalDataProvider`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const DataContext = React.createContext();
export default DataContext;

export class DataProvider extends Component {

  state = {
     title: 'Some title'
  }

  render() {
   return (
     <DataContext.Provider 
       value={{state: this.state}}>
       {this.props.children}
     </DataContext.Provider>
    )}
}
```

And I am trying to use data in another file "PageSection.js" like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import DataContext from '../data/GlobalDataProvider';

const PageSection= () =>{

return (
    <section className="page-section">
        <DataContext.Consumer>
            {(context) => (
                <h1>{ context.state.title }</h1>
            )}
        </DataContext.Consumer>
    </section>
 );
};
```

However this does not work for some reason. I get this error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined, 
  in PageSection.js line 11 (the line with this code: { context.state.title }).
```

What am I doing wrong?

Do I have to import the class DataProvider? or only the Context variable?

Comment: can you do a `console.log(JSON.stringify(context))` to dump what context actually looks like?

Comment: I get Undefined

Comment: You have to actually render the Provider in as a parent of the Consumer

Comment: Can you give me code example, I will give best answer if it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you need your DataContext.Consumer to be a child element of the DataContext.Provider.  Something like this...

```
import React from 'react';
import DataContext, { DataProvider } from '../data/GlobalDataProvider';

const PageSection= () =>{

return (
    <section className="page-section">
      <DataProvider>
        <DataContext.Consumer>
            {(context) => (
                <h1>{ context.state.title }</h1>
            )}
        </DataContext.Consumer>
      </DataProvider>
    </section>
 );
};
```

Comment: That does it, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
export class DataProvider extends Component {

  state = {
     title: 'Some title'
  }

  render() {
   return (
     <DataContext.Provider 
       value={this.state}>
       {this.props.children}
     </DataContext.Provider>
    )}
}






const PageSection= () =>{

return (
  <DataProvider>
    <section className="page-section">
        <DataContext.Consumer>
            {(context) => (
                <h1>{ context.title }</h1>
            )}
        </DataContext.Consumer>
    </section>
 </DataProvider>
 );
};
```

Comment: console logging context gives undefined, so there is something wrong with the import export propabbly, this does not work (undefined.title = undifined)

Comment: then your path import DataContext from '../data/GlobalDataProvider'; is probably wrong

Comment: I checked, and it is not the case. I am importing the variable called "DataContext", should I import the class called "DataProvider" instead (both in GlobalDataProvider.js)?

Comment: yes and you need to wrap it around the consumer, ill update my code