# React: How can I pass data between independent components

Tags: reactjs

I known how to pass data from a component to other but what I want to do is to have two independent component where one of them pass data to the other.

For example, `<Component 1>` pass data to `<Component 2>`. I don't want to pass data to `<Component 2>` inside the code of `<Component 1>`. What I want to know if its possible to pass data and how from `<Component 1>` to `<Component 2>`. Because, I want to have an independent component which makes its own tasks and at the end of these tasks, pass the data to other component which is not included in her own code.

This would be an example what I would like to do:

```
class Test extends Component{
   constructor(){
       super()
   }

   render(){
      return(
         <div>
              <h1>Test</h1>
              <Component 1 />
              <Component 2 />
         </div>
      )
   }
}
```

Therefore, is there any way to pass data between independent components in React.js?.

Comment: you can use the `context` api for this.

Comment: Thank you @JohnRuddell!!! Any example have you got?

Comment: @JoséCarlos Have a look at my answer with an example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51248277/how-to-get-data-from-react-context/51248710#51248710 ... an example

Comment: @JoséCarlos You don't need Context API for such a small one... Just use your parent's states.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman context would be the correct way to go. Just because you can use a parent state doesn't mean its the correct way to do it. The OP wants an uncontrolled set of components that talk to each other, not a parent controlling them via state. Especially if other future components are not at the same level as this, but nested a few levels in

Comment: @JoséCarlos the link Doug posted is a good example :) its pretty easy to setup the context and pass stuff around :) If you have issues setting up from examples / documentation let me know and I can write up something for you! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const { useState, createContext, useContext } = React;
const Context = React.createContext();

const MyComponent = () => {
  const { name, updateName } = useContext(Context);
  return (<span onClick={() => updateName('Jane')}>{name}</span>);
};

const App = () => {
  const [name, updateName] = useState('John');
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ name, updateName }}>
      <MyComponent />
      <br/>
      <MyComponent />
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

to exercise the snippet...
  click on John to update name to Jane

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `state` in the parent component that holds both the components and use some way of updating the parent state by the child component and consume it, in its basic way. Advanced way is to use Redux, but I don't think your current example needs it.

Let me show you a small example.

```js
const Component1 = props => (
  <div>
    <h1>Component 1</h1>
    <p>Please change the value here:</p>
    <input
      type="text"
      onChange={e => props.changeState(e.target.value)}
      value={props.value}
    />
  </div>
);
const Component2 = props => (
  <div>
    <h1>Component 2</h1>
    <p>Let me show the common value here:</p>
    <pre>{props.value}</pre>
  </div>
);

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    commonValue: "Hello"
  };
  changeState = val => {
    this.setState({
      commonValue: val
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Component1
          value={this.state.commonValue}
          changeState={this.changeState}
        />
        <Component2 value={this.state.commonValue} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This way, you will be able to change the values from two different components.

**Working Snippet**

```js
const Component1 = props => (
  <div>
    <h1>Component 1</h1>
    <p>Please change the value here:</p>
    <input
      type="text"
      onChange={e => props.changeState(e.target.value)}
      value={props.value}
    />
  </div>
);
const Component2 = props => (
  <div>
    <h1>Component 2</h1>
    <p>Let me show the common value here:</p>
    <pre>{props.value}</pre>
  </div>
);

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    commonValue: "Hello"
  };
  changeState = val => {
    this.setState({
      commonValue: val
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Component1
          value={this.state.commonValue}
          changeState={this.changeState}
        />
        <Component2 value={this.state.commonValue} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Working Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-sea-e7d99**

Comment: Thank you so much @PraveenKumarPurushothaman for your explanation and example. Your solution is the best approach to that I want to do. Thanks a lot for your appreciated help and thank you so much to the others contributors!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have dependent data for independent components - you need to lift your state up to a common parent component.

For your particular example, the `Test` component might contain data needed to be shared between `Component1` and `Component2` as well as handlers for its changing.

You can read more about this in official documentation about [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).